# Display Base64 image in Discord.js Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, discord.js, base64

I'm currently struggling with a base64 image, which I'm trying to display in the thumbnail of an embed post with discord.js.

The image link, after a first processing to get only the image link :
`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS[...]N02ziqF8weBaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`

My code :

```
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/${host}:${port}`); //:${port}
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);
  if (json !='') {
 try {


    var imageStream = Buffer.from(json.icon.split(",")[1], "base64");
    var img = new AttachmentBuilder(imageStream, {name : "favicon.png"});
    console.log(typeof img);
    console.log(img);

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(host)
    .setThumbnail("attachment://favicon.png")

    [...]

    await interaction.editReply({embeds: [embed]});

 } catch (error) {
    await interaction.editReply({content: `Une erreur est survenue : ${error}`, ephemeral: true });
 }
```

The result:
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwbVh.png)

I've already looked at the different solutions given here for decoding a base64 image, but so far none have worked.

When I try to display the image as a file in the interaction response, I get:
TypeError [ReqResourceType]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.